# Databind ObservableCollection<Object> to DataGrid WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, datagrid

i have a xaml page in namespace Dca.KnxPanel.View with a Datagrid defined as

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Name="GroupAddressDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static viewModel:DcaAppVm._ProjectGroupAddress}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="14,0,-14,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
    <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
    </Border>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Address"  Binding="{Binding Path=Address_Value}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Datapoint_Name}" Width="Auto"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Path=Datapoint_Object_Size}" Width="Auto"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

where the DCA_GroupAddressList and DCA_GroupAddress are defined as in the namespace Dca.KnxPanel.Model

```
namespace Dca.KnxPanel.Model
{
    [DebuggerDisplay("{Address_Value} {Datapoint_Name} {Datapoint_Object_Size}")]
    public class DCA_GroupAddress
    {
        public DCA_GroupAddress(GroupAddress data) {
            Address_Value = data.AddressValue.ToString();
            Datapoint_Name = data.Name;
            if (data.ObjectSize != null)
            {
                Datapoint_Object_Size = data.ObjectSize.Value;
            }
        }

        public string Address_Value { get; set; }
        public string Datapoint_Name { get; set; }
        public ObjectSize Datapoint_Object_Size { get; set; }

    }

    public class DCA_GroupAddressList : ObservableCollection<DCA_GroupAddress>
    {

        public static DCA_GroupAddressList dca_groupaddresslist { get; set; }

        public void Add(GroupAddress item)
        {
            this.Add(new DCA_GroupAddress(item));
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, item));
        }

        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action != null)
            {
                base.OnCollectionChanged(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the Binding data in DataGrid not works but i don't understand why...

Can you help me?

Comment: You are binding the ItemsSource to `DcaAppVm._ProjectGroupAddress`. What is that? We only see a static `DCA_GroupAddressList.dca_groupaddresslist` property, which is apparently never initialized or populated. There would be no need for static properties at all, if you would simply assign the view's DataContext correctly. Also be aware that you do not need to manually call OnCollectionChanged. Overriding that method is also pointless. Remove all that redundant stuff.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried many solution and at the end this is what works:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Name="GroupAddressDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding _ProjectGroupAddress}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="14,0,-14,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" >
                            <Border Background="GhostWhite" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" BorderThickness="1">
                            </Border>
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Group Address"  Binding="{Binding Path=Address_Value}" Width="Auto"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Path=Datapoint_Name}" Width="Auto"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length" Binding="{Binding Path=Datapoint_Object_Size}" Width="Auto"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
```

The class DCA_GroupAddress now is:

```
 public class DCA_GroupAddress : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string address_value, datapoint_name;
        private ObjectSize datapoint_object_size;

        public DCA_GroupAddress(GroupAddress data) {
            Address_Value = data.AddressValue.ToString();
            Datapoint_Name = data.Name;
            if (data.ObjectSize != null)
            {
                Datapoint_Object_Size = data.ObjectSize.Value;
            }
        }

        public string Address_Value { 
            get { return address_value; }
            set {
                address_value = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("address_value")); 
            } 
        }
        public string Datapoint_Name
        {
            get { return datapoint_name; }
            set
            {
                datapoint_name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("datapoint_name")); 
            }
        }
        public ObjectSize Datapoint_Object_Size
        {
            get { return datapoint_object_size; }

            set
            {
                datapoint_object_size = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("datapoint_object_size"));
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

and i have define a container

```
public ObservableCollection<DCA_GroupAddress> _ProjectGroupAddress { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<DCA_GroupAddress>();
```

**my question is why i need to add these code**:

```
            GroupAddressDataGrid.Items.Clear();
            GroupAddressDataGrid.ItemsSource = _ProjectGroupAddress;
```

in the UI class constructor? Seems that Items are not empty when the DataGrid is created so the software not use the ItemsSource. I need to clear the items before the binding works...

Thanks

Comment: Show how you set the DataContext with the container you specify.

Comment: In the XAML ? Ok, setting these code  <br/>              `<DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2"  Name="GroupAddressDataGrid" DataContext="{Binding _ProjectGroupAddress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type view:DcaAppUi}}}" ItemsSource="{Binding _ProjectGroupAddress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type view:DcaAppUi}}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="Auto" >`  <br/> works